# Mongo Database Connectivity from Java

Tags: java, mongodb, virtual-machine, database

Just playing around with virtual servers, trying to improve my skills.

So i'm trying to connect to a locally hosted mongoDB and having some issues. Want to iterate over a collection and get some output so I know I'm connected sort of thing. Problem is I cant see an easy way to convert the collection (I think I have) to something java understands. I'm running mongo3.2 using the 3.4 java drivers. Also I am running Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters.
Still haven't got copy and paste to my virtual machine to work so I will attach a couple of pictures showing the state of database.[image][image]
And here is my java app code

```
static String user = "guest";
static String database = "VsJogger";
static char[] password = {'g','u','e','s','t'};
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user,
                                                                  database,
                                                                  password);

    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://"+user+":"
            +String.valueOf(password)
            +"@localhost/?authSource="+database);

   try{

     // To connect to mongodb server
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( uri);


     // Now connect to your databases
     MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("VsJogger");
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
     MongoCollection coll = db.getCollection("Jog");
     MongoCursor<Document> cursor = coll.find().iterator();

     int i = 1;
     while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
        System.out.println("Inserted Document: "+i); 
        System.out.println(cursor.next()); 
        i++;
     }


  }catch(Exception e){
     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
  }
```

and output.

```
Oct 23, 2016 3:59:45 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Connect to database successfully
Oct 23, 2016 3:59:45 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Oct 23, 2016 3:59:46 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more

com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect}}]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 31 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably should have been more clear. I was using an Ubuntu virtual machine running on windows (virtual box) to host the server and trying to access it from windows.

Fixed by altering the mongo configuration file to include the 192.xx.. address of the virtual machine and then used that when connecting through java. The loopback address 'localhost' is unique to the machine ie. my virtual machine and therfore wasn't accessible to my main system.